# NodeJS google-translate-api BAD_REQUEST

Tags: node.js, google-translation-api

So the example given is as follows

```
const translate = require('google-translate-api');

translate('Ik spreek Engels', {to: 'en'}).then(res => {
    console.log(res.text);
    //=> I speak English
    console.log(res.from.language.iso);
    //=> nl
}).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

With the following error message

> { Error
>       at /var/www/translate/node_modules/google-translate-api/index.js:105:17
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:160:7) code: 'BAD_REQUEST' }

This is a basic set up if someone has resolved this issue please post - thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise you to use the [official client library from Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs). Be aware though, that there is [no free quota](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#access_to_the_api_name) for the Translate API. The sample code would look as follows:

```
const {Translate} = require('@google-cloud/translate');

const projectId = 'YOUR_PROJECT_ID';

const translate = new Translate({   projectId: projectId, });

const text = 'Hello, world!'; 

const target = 'ru';

translate   
    .translate(text, target)   .then(results => {
      const translation = results[0];
      console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
      console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);   
    })   
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('ERROR:', err);   
    });
```